# springboot2.7.14 StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]/TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start

Tags: spring-boot, java-11

springboot version:2.7.14
jdk：11.0.15

Srpingboot start failed,full stack as below:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.taobao.pandora.boot.loader.LaunchRunner.run(LaunchRunner.java:32)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.fliggy.service.appeal.Application.main(Application.java:22)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[] failed to start
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.rethrowDeferredStartupExceptions(TomcatWebServer.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126)
    ... 19 more
```

I got two question:
1.Does springboot2.7.14 compatible to jdk11?
2.How can i solve this problem?

I found that it was caused by another jar package， The servlet version used is as follows:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>99.0-does-not-exist</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>servlet-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>999-no-exist-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>999-not-exist-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you also update the question with `pom.xml` or `gradle.build` file ?